# Why this code adding empty img tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code allows the user to enter a search term, and then presents a series of images from Flickr that have that tag. This works as intended but I can't understand why this generates so many img tags.

```
var main = function () {
    "use strict";

    var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=catss&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?";


    var $searchInput = $("<input>");

    $("header").append($searchInput);


    $.getJSON(url, function (flickrResponse) {

        flickrResponse.items.forEach(function (photo) {

            var $img = $("<img>").hide();

            $img.attr("src", photo.media.m);


            $searchInput.on("keypress", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    $img.remove();
                    $img.removeAttr('src');

                    var $tag = photo.tags.split(" ");

                    $tag.forEach(function (tag) {
                        if (tag === $searchInput.val()) {
                            $img.attr("src", photo.media.m);
                        }
                    });
                    $("main .photos").append($img);
                    $img.fadeIn();
                }
            });
            $("main .photos").append($img);
            $img.fadeIn();

        });   
    }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
        alert("Request Failed: " + err);
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

The above code results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <body>
      <header><input></header>
      <main>
         <div class="photos">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style=""   src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8299/7875996296_734b9c599d_m.jpg">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
             <img style="">
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer> </footer>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
      <script src="javascripts/app.js">
     </body>
 </html>
```

Why it is adding so many img tags?

Comment: Beacause of `flickrResponse.items.forEach`. If you're after help, pls create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Fiddle means using this site http://jsfiddle.net or other similar to show us a ~ working example

Comment: [Code on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1s3kdau/#&togetherjs=PxoTvdbvwG) well i've added code on fiddle but i'm having a problem to get it run.

Comment: @tasqyn that link is not to jsfiddle :)

Comment: @Nenotlep sorry accidently pasted :)

Comment: @tasqyn For me that JSFiddle returns cat pictures as expected. Works fine. I had to remove SSL (https) though to prevent encryption from klling the requests; forked working exapmple at http://jsfiddle.net/Nenotlep/bu7oosf2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new keydown handler for each item in the returned array, also you should use hide/show of iamges instead removing and setting blank src

```js
var main = function() {
  "use strict";

  var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=catss&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

  var $searchInput = $("<input>");

  $searchInput.on("keypress", function(event) {
    var term = this.value;
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      $("main .photos img").hide().each(function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        var tags = $img.data('tags');

        if (tags.indexOf(term) > -1) {
          $img.fadeIn();
        }
      })
    }
  });

  $("header").append($searchInput);

  $.getJSON(url, function(flickrResponse) {
    flickrResponse.items.forEach(function(photo) {
      console.log('x')
      var $img = $("<img>", {
        src: photo.media.m
      }).hide().data('tags', photo.tags.split(/\s+/));
      $("main .photos").append($img);
      $img.fadeIn();
    });
  }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
    alert("Request Failed: " + err);
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<main>
  <div class="photos"></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this line

```
 $("main .photos").append($img);
```

added inside a forEach thats why the html markup is getting the image tag appended multiple times under the div which has the class 'photos'.

UPDATE (to prevent empty img tag to appended):

```
var main = function () {
    "use strict";

    var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=catss&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?";


    var $searchInput = $("<input>");

    $("header").append($searchInput);


    $.getJSON(url, function (flickrResponse) {

        flickrResponse.items.forEach(function (photo) {

            var $img = $("<img>").hide();

            $img.attr("src", photo.media.m);


            $searchInput.on("keypress", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    $img.remove();
                    $img.removeAttr('src');

                    var $tag = photo.tags.split(" ");

                    $tag.forEach(function (tag) {
                        if (tag === $searchInput.val()) {
                            $img.attr("src", photo.media.m);
                            $("main .photos").append($img);
                            $img.fadeIn();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            //$("main .photos").append($img);
            //$img.fadeIn();

        });   
    }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
        alert("Request Failed: " + err);
    });
};
```

Comment: how to prevent to add empty img tags?

Comment: it prevents but when it is run for the first time it does not show all images. well thank you for your help :)